# Custom Launcher not appearing in Launcher list

Tags: java, android, xml

When I run my Launcher on my phone, and then press the home button, Android displays a popup asking which Launcher I would like to set as the default. My Launcher never appears in this list.

I have set appropriate intents in the ApplicationManifest.xml file (MAIN, HOME, DEFAULT).

From what I have read, and seen in sample launchers, that is all that's required.

How do I get it to show my Launcher in this list?

In addition to this, if I manually go to Settings > Home > Set my custom Launcher as default, then press the home button, Android again asks me which Launcher I want as default, but still does not display my custom Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the user had set some other app as default launcher app.That might be the reason that system is not showing an option to select the home app.

Clear default launcher by going to Settings->Applications->Default Applications->Home and try the use case again.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your suggestion, but my Launcher still doesn't appear in that list.